# Android Toggle Button with timed delay off

Tags: java, android, button

I would like to create a toggle button that when pressed has about a 1 second delay and toggles off.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
       // Relay On
    } else {
        // Relay Off
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read setTimeout() function is your best bet. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp has a tutorial on it's use.
I imagine it could be used something like this.

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
// Is the toggle on?
boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

if (on) {
   // Relay On
   setTimeout(toggle(){((ToggleButton) view).setChecked(false)},1000);
} else {
    // Relay Off
}
}
```